# In Java is there any way to get the AWT Component object by specifying x and y position?

Tags: java, awt

In Java, I am having a AWT frame and added four AWT components inside the frame, these AWT components are positioned using AbsoluteLayout.

Now I need to know is there any way for me to get the AWT component instance if I pass the x and y position?

Comment: "*..get the AWT component instance if I pass the x and y position?"* Why?  What application feature does that support?  Note that if you add a `MouseListener` or `MouseMotionListener` the pointer can be used to identify the component.  For a more robust GUI, ***use** (non-absolute, non-null) **layouts.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always query the parent component using `getComponentAt()`

```
public Component getComponentAt(int x, int y)

Determines if this component or one of its immediate subcomponents contains
the (x, y) location, and if so, returns the containing component. This method
only looks one level deep. If the point (x, y) is inside a subcomponent that
itself has subcomponents, it does not go looking down the subcomponent tree.

The locate method of Component simply returns the component itself if the (x, y) coordinate location is inside its bounding box, and null otherwise.

    Parameters:
        x - the x coordinate
        y - the y coordinate 
    Returns:
        the component or subcomponent that contains the (x, y) location; null if the location is outside this component
    Since:
        JDK1.0
    See Also:
        contains(int, int)
```

Java 7 : 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getComponentAt%28int,%20int%29

Java 6 : 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getComponentAt%28int,%20int%29

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponentAt%28int,%20int%29):

```
Container.getComponentAt()
```